# C - threads and processes - prevent zombies

Tags: c, multithreading, process, fork

I'm implementing a function which receives a parsed-to-array command lines (`"./waiter 20 &"` will be parsed, and the function will receive the array 
`{"./waiter","20","&"}` for example).
If the last argument is &, the process should run in the background.
To prevent zombies, I need to use a new thread that will wait for the child process. 
The attached code is my working program, and all my efforts to add a new thread that will wait for the child process failed. 
Anyone can guide me? 
Attaching the code, with some of the leftovers of my unsuccessful tries.
(the function is `process_arglist`)

update: after a lot of tries using what suggested here, its still failing and im not sure why. updated code attached.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void func(void* ptr) {
    pid_t* mypid = (pid_t*)ptr;
    waitpid(*mypid);
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
}

int process_arglist(int count, char** arglist){
    int isBackground = 0;
    pid_t  pid;
    int    status;
    char** parsedList;
    if (strcmp(arglist[count-1],"&") == 0) {
        printf("###we are in the & situation\n");
        parsedList = (char**)malloc((count-1)*sizeof(char*));
        if (parsedList == NULL) {
            printf( "Error: malloc failed - %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<count-1;i++){
            parsedList[i] = arglist[i];
        }
        /*printf("parsed list:\n");
        for (i=0;i<count-1;i++) {
            printf(" %d: %s\n", i,parsedList[i]);
        }*/
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {     /* fork a child process           */
            printf( "Error: fork failed");
            exit(0);
        } else if (pid == 0) {          /* for the child process:         */
            if (execvp(*parsedList,parsedList) < 0) {     /* execute the command  */
                printf( "Error: execvp failed - %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(0);
            }
        } else {
            pthread_t thread;
            pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (void*) &func, (void*) &pid);
        }
    } else {
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {     /* fork a child process           */
            printf( "Error: forking child process failed - %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {          /* for the child process:         */
            if (execvp(*arglist,arglist) < 0) {     /* execute the command  */
                printf( "Error: execvp failed - %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else {                                  /* for the parent:      */
            while (waitpid(&status) != pid);       /* wait for completion  */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What threading model or library are you using? POSIX pthreads? Win32 threads?

Comment: POSIX i assume (im using linux ubuntu)

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ).  The compiler raises two warnings. 1) unused variable: `isBackground`  2) 64:1: warnings: control reaches end of non-void function.  the non void function is: ` process_arglist()`

Comment: for readability and understandability by us humans, please separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a blank line.  Please use meaningful names for functions and variables.  `func()` is not a meaningful name in this scenario.

Comment: when calling: `malloc()` and family of functions, 1) in C, do not cast the returned value.  The type is already `void *` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  2) casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: the prototype for the signature of a function that is executed via a call to `pthread_create()` is `void* (*)( void*)`  not `void (*)(void*) so the signature of `func()` should be: `void * func( void * ptr)`

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <sys/wait.h>`

Comment: in general, a return value of 0 indicates success.  However, a 0 is being returned at several points in the code when the actual status is failure.  Suggest the calls to `exit()` be written as: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: The parameter list to waitpid() is not correct, please read the man page.  Perhaps you actually wanted to use `wait()`

Comment: regarding this line: `if (execvp(*arglist,arglist) < 0) { `,  the `execvp()` function only returns if there was an error.  so no need for an `'if` statement and it does not return a status value.

Comment: calling `fork()` results in a background process for the 'child'  so the function: `process_arglist()` is operating under some mis-conceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, switch from calling `wait` to calling `waitpid`. Otherwise, if you have more than one thread waiting, they'll steal each other's notifications.

Second, break the call to `waitpid` into its own function that takes the PID to wait for as a parameter. Cast it through `void *`, since that's what's used for thread parameters.

Third, change the call to the function to a call to `pthread_create`, casting the PID to wait for to a `void *` to pass to the newly-created thread.

Lastly, have the thread detach itself, since there won't be anything waiting for the thread to terminate.

Comment: you meant i need to change from wait to waitpid in the line 
while (wait(&status) != pid); ?

Comment: @GumBi Yes, for the reason I explained.